# Python solution to transforming polar stereographic data to mercator projection

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, matplotlib-basemap

I've data in polar stereographic projection and the lat and lon values as well. But I cannot seem to find a simple way to transform this to a mercator (regular square lat and lon) projection in Basemap. Does anyone have a simple solution to this problem?

Appreciate your help with this,
/M

Comment: [This](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/mapcoords.html) should solve your doubts. If you can't figure it out, maybe you can provide us with a small working example.

Comment: Are you wanting to regrid data? Or just transform the coordinates?

Comment: @Jaime and Pelson - I want to transform the data. I thought about regridding but I heard that regridding is a bad idea. Tried Jaime's suggestion and what got was a mercator projection but a warped image of the data when plotted with m.pcolor(xpt,ypt,data). 
    m = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=27.0,urcrnrlat=77,\
            llcrnrlon=61.0,urcrnrlon=-23.0,lat_ts=20,resolution='c')
    xpt,ypt = m(lon_m,lat_m)
    m.pcolor(xpt,ypt,co_intm) 
    plt.show()

[fig](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bu675nzd62xlqfs/proj_fig.png)
[data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uggqiequf69sibf/proj_variables.npz)

Comment: @pelson - see comment above.

Comment: @pelson - can we discuss the map transformation question?

Comment: Thanks for the nudge @Shejo284. How I see your problem: You have a 2d array of data, a 2d array of latitudes and a 2d array of longitudes, and you'd ultimately like to plot them on a Mercator map, right?

Comment: @pelson - yes, that is the gist of it. What it is, more specifically, is that I would like to plot a rotated lat lon grid in mercator projection using python. Many of the examples I found just does not work and I'm beginning to think that it is not possible. Part of the problem is that when you try interpolate, much of the mercator domain remains outside the rotated lonlat domain and therefore needs some form of extrapolation. This is very ugly. I found a possible solution but this is using a package called NCL: [example solution](http://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Applications/rotatedltln.shtml).

Comment: Thanks @Shejo284 - I've got the jist of it now. Another example, for the record: http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/advanced_plotting.html#block-plots

Comment: I'll put together an example using Basemap in a short while.

Comment: @pelson - those examples look good. I tried to install Cartopy and Iris on my Mac but it failed. I'll see if my IT dept can install them on the linux cluster.

Comment: Did you see this: https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/48 ?

Comment: @pelson - I have macport on my laptop. Tried brew once before but there were many conflicts with macport. Plus, brew is not yet as extensive as macport in terms of software.