# Polar stereographic to regular lat/lon grid python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib-basemap

I have data in a 448 by 304 array, in a polar stereographic format. I've attached an image of a simple pyplot of this below. For the curious, its of north pole ice (i.e the blue island mass just below the center of the image is Greenland. [image]

I woudl like to interpolate/regrid this data onto a regular lat/lon grid, of say size 180x360 (latitude -90 to 90, longitude -180 to 180) - 1 degree resolution.

Info I have for this is that the center of the plot (150,224) corresponds to (0,0) (north pole), each box is 25km by 25km, and the corner latitude/longitudes (defined here http://nsidc.org/sites/nsidc.org/files/images/data/polar-stereo/ssmi_gridmap_arctic.gif).

Is there a basemap way to do this? I don't want to visualise the data, but have it in a regular lat/lon grid so i can compare to other data.

Can attach the data in .nc format if it helps.

Many thanks,
James

Comment: This discussion can be a starting point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574507/python-solution-to-transforming-polar-stereographic-data-to-mercator-projection